# LWC onClick for div not returning id or data-id for either target or currentTarget

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, template

Here is another issue I can't seem to figure out, had it working in past project, did the exact same thing and nothing.

No matter what I try the event param will not give back the id set in the template.  Here is the pertinent code...

Template

```
<div key={it.value.id} id={it.value.Id} class="slds-m-top_xxx-small slds-m-bottom_x-large list-item" onclick={handleListClick}>

<!-- have also tried -->
<div key={it.value.id} data-id={it.value.Id} class="slds-m-top_xxx-small slds-m-bottom_x-large list-item" onclick={handleListClick}>
```

Javascript

```
handleListClick(event) {
    console.log('bw: id = ' + event.currentTarget.id);
    // output: bw: id = undefined

    // have also tried
    console.log('bw: id = ' + event.currentTarget.dataset.id);
    // output: bw: id = undefined

    //have also tried
    let t = event.currentTarget;
    let idstr = t.getAttribute("id");
    console.log('bw: id = ' + idstr);
    // output: bw: id = null
```

any time I used data-id I used dataset when trying to retrieve the value.

Also in the inspector on chrome if I look at the element, neither the id nor the data-id shows elements tree.  I have spent hours trying to figure this out so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem with your code is in key attribute you have passed **{it.value.id}** where as for data-id you have passed **{it.value.Id}**. Both are different as you have used capital and small **i** . JavaScript is case sensitive. Check the correct api name for id. Use exactly in your html code.

`event.currentTarget.dataset.id` or `event.target.dataset.id` would log the value of data-id.

Comment: Thanks, was staring at it for hours, and just didn't see it!

Comment: It happens if you are working with JavaScript

Comment: This doesn't work if you in render in the light mode, I mean when your LWC Html starts with <template lwc:render-mode='light'>
Light mode is documented here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.create_light_dom